# Can you change the order of JMenuItems?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

This a really straightforward question. Can I change the order of [`JMenuItems`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html) in a [`JPopupMenu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#:%7E:text=A%20JPopupMenu%20is%20used%20for,want%20a%20menu%20to%20appear.)? Or is there a way to specify something like an index when adding a menu item to a popup menu like you can with a list (e.i. [`List.add(int, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-))?

Context: I have an abstract class which is adding a menu item to a popup menu in the super constructor. I want to insert menu items before that item in the child class' constructor.

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following method of JPopupMenu?

```
void insert(Component component, int index)
```

Comment: Well what do ya' know! Works like a charm. Thank you!